# Move/reorder columns in a spark DataGrid (Adobe Flex)

Tags: apache-flex, flex-spark

I am unable to find if the spark DataGrid supports moving / reordering the columns.
If not what could be the best solution? Maybe using the mx version?

I want the user to be able to drag the columns and arrange them.

Comment: Do you mean reordering by dragging the column/s?

Answer (score 1):

From Adobe Flex 4.6 - Spark DataGrid control, configuring columns:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS0ab2a460655f2dc3-427f401412c60d04dca-8000.html

> Note: You can only sort the columns of the DataGrid programmatically
>   by sorting the IList passed to the columns property. That is, you
>   cannot use the mouse to drag a column to rearrange the columns.

Therefore you would need a programmatic implementation to reorder GridColumns in the columns IList.

```
    <s:columns> 
        <s:ArrayList>
            <s:GridColumn dataField="Album"/> 
            <s:GridColumn dataField="Price"/> 
        </s:ArrayList>
    </s:columns>
```

Comment: Thx, then I have 2 solutions that I must investigate, ! extend the DataGrid from spark or 2 use the mx DataGrid . Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

```
   //adg is your DataGrid id
   var tmp:ArrayList = adg.columns as ArrayList;
   var col:GridColumn = new GridColumn('customColumn'); //create new col or reuse existing from tmp
   tmp.setItemAt(col, 1); //set it at the position you want
```

Comment: I edited my question, I need the user to be able to drag the columns and move them, any hints on that?

Comment: well... implement it yourself or use the `AdvancedDataGrid` with `draggableColumns`

Answer (score 0):

costin from http://flex6packs.wordpress.com/2012/01/18/spark-grid-column-drag-and-drop-or-move/ has working code of extending DataGrid to support draggable columns.